# A file for comments

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, comments

I wrote an app in which there is a ton of comments.

This may be a bit unusual, but **I would like to know if there is a way in Visual Studio to elegantly arrange the comments in a dedicated file.** Or, is there a way to write text somewhere in a text file?

It is true that using comments is great, but my code is still congested.

Currently I plan to use a new class for comments, which will only contain comments with details on the parts of the code that are concerned.

If you have a better idea, thank you very much for sharing it.

Comment: My first thought is 'why'? Why so much code comments? Either explain it better in person, or rewrite it so it is easier to understand and you don't need them anymore or write a manual/blogpost that takes care of the explaining part. That said, maybe you should use the [xml doc features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/how-to-use-the-xml-documentation-features) and have a documentation tool generate a super fancy layout for them.

Comment: Maybe transfer the comments to a functional design document? Only comment code that doesn't show immediately what is done. Don't go too far in depth describing what is done in code comments, do this in an external document. Assume a base knowledge, then add what is missing. If you need more than 10-20 words, you probably don't understand the essence what is being done or the code is too complex and needs breaking down in smaller bits.

Comment: Okay, thank you all, I'll take your recommendations into consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't stress enough how much of a bad idea this is.

Code comments are best:

1. Being near the code they concern
2. Short and simple
3. Used sparingly - code often changes, comments can very quickly fall out of sync with this, and then before you know it the comments are doing more harm than good.

If there really is some **functional** explanation you're trying to get across, e.g. **why** something is needed and **how** it works, rather than **how** to use it, I'd recommend writing a document to explain this.

There are all sorts of ways to do this:

1. Word documents on a shared system (e.g. a network drive / sharepoint)
2. A wiki system online / internally (e.g. Atlassian Confluence, or GitHub wiki)

(to name a couple)

As per other user's suggestions though, you should ensure that there aren't a lot of comments as they just add noise (something you're clearly discovering).

Sidenote: I once worked for a company that **insisted** on using comments **everywhere**, every function had to have a banner comment with its name, signature, who wrote it and an edit history (even though we used source control), and nearly every line of code had to be commented to state what it was (supposedly) doing. If you're in a similar position, perhaps try to explain the problems this causes?

Comment: Thank you very much, I finally used Notepad. The application in question is actually a personal application but I wrote it in a somewhat unusual way for me. This is why I have commented on many parts of the code to explain their importance, role and use ... It is also because I intend to share this application later.